# Submitted Resume with Factual Mistake - Just noticed! What to do?

Tags: resume

I submitted a copy of my resume through a company's application web app. Also have a connection there and had them pass another copy along to the relevant parties. After the fact, I felt my resume was rather weak and began to edit it for future rounds of submissions... Then I noticed I had a factual error on the last line of my work experience on the copy I submitted!

YIKES!

It was something overlooked by my proof readers who didn't know the technical details of the project I was listing. Basically I had a bit about a project I worked on that involved XML but I accidentally typed CSS instead and never caught it... My resume is corrected now but not sure what to do about this recent submission. I'd hate to keep trying to pull strings and running my connection around having them submit copy after copy.

Should I just wait to see if I get an interview and then hope they don't ask about that project? Or should I fess up if they do ask about that project (not sure I could effectively BS about why we used CSS for something CSS can't do)?

I always bring copies of my resume with me to interviews; now that its significantly different, should I bring a corrected older version, or bring the newest version (also corrected)? How should I handle such a dramatic change in resume format between what I submitted, and what I bring with me (trying to stay positive and assuming I get an interview)?

Or should I beg, plead, apologize, and send gifts to get my contact to bring the corrected or new formatted corrected version of my resume back to those doing the hiring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly? Stop stressing about it.

In technical positions a resume is largely used as a screening tool. The HR rep checks it out, maybe someone on the team checks it out and, if they are at all interested, an interview is scheduled. When you go to an interview ensure you bring several copies of the most recent, up-to-date resume you have. If/when you are talking about that project just ignore the CSS and jump straight into talking about the XML.

There are, really, only a couple of possible results here:

1. They are so concerned about hiring someone who has used XML that
   they screen all resumes that do not mention it. If this is the case
   you may not get the interview. If your resume is otherwise weak then
   it's possible that this is a tipping point but, really, it's so
   minor it's probably not. If you've done any programming the
   expectation is that, of course, you know XML.
2. They are so concerned about hiring someone who has used CSS that
   they screen all resumes for CSS and pull those that mention it. If
   this is the case you get a bonus interview! But, again, this is so
   minor that a single word switch probably won't tip it either way.
3. You make a big deal out of a minor mistake. Sure the company may get
   an updated resume but, at the same time, you now come across as
   someone who doesn't have their shit together. Whether or not you
   would have gotten  an interview before you have unfortunately tipped
   the odds against that to some degree. Some places might be pretty
   laid back about it, some places will think you're a doofus for
   making a big deal out of something so tiny. This, of course, would
   also depend on how far along the resume has gotten in the process.

Your best case scenario right now is to let it go. Update your resume, strengthen it across the board, bring new resumes to the interview. If anyone brings up the new format be honest - "I felt my old resume was weak representation of my strengths as a cadidate". If someone brings up the one word 'mistake' then handle it with grace - "CSS? Oh dear that must have been a mistake, I should have put XML and this is how we used it ... "

Comment: Have to agree here. You don't get a job based on the resume. You get the job based on the results of the interview (the resume is just a way to get passed HR to the hiring manager).

Answer (score 2):

Minor erratum. You can fix your error at any stage (because it is a minor erratum). Make sure you know your CSS3 and your JSON and your error will be a lot less than it looks - I hate XML and most of us who hate XML hope that XML disappears off the face of the Earth.